# Redirect to an external site when accessing the page of a node meeting a set of condition

Tags: 7, redirection

I need to redirect users to an external website when they access the node view page at `node/%node` of a node meeting some conditions.

What would the proper/best way to achieve this (using code) be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`hook_node_view`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7).

Remember to check the view mode along with the conditions, so you don't redirect on pages where only the teaser is shown.

It should look something like this:

```
module_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full' && "Conditions") {
    drupal_goto('http://example.com');
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it documented/accepted that the 'full' view mode should only be used when the node is displayed by itself as a page? In Drupal 6, I would to it in hook_nodeapi when $op == 'view' and $a4 == TRUE.

Comment: I found node_is_page($node) to add as condition to ensure the node is displayed itself as a page before redirecting to an external site. This should also protected against redirection during content indexation on cron.

Answer (score 0):

We created a content type using [CCK Redirection](http://drupal.org/project/cck_redirection) and then external links could be treated like nodes.  So you could use node access modules, the rules module, etc.  It has worked quite well for us.