# Change URL of Node Title

Tags: rules, feeds

Bit of an odd request. I want to somehow change/alias the URL of a node to an external website. We are importing a calendar of events from our booking vendor to show nicely on our page. In the end, the user must go to the booking vendor website to enroll though. While I want all the imported data to be able to be shown on our website (so we can show snippets in blocks, and so forth), I want the node link to go to the event on the booking website. Our import does include the booking URL for each event.

I tried using the rules module to overwite the node:url on import, but it obviously does not allow this. I assume I could work some wizardry in views, but I would need the URL to change for blocks, calendar views, list views, etc. Is there some way to make a node always redirect to an external URL based on the import I am using "Feeds import" with an iCal feed?

To make it harder, I also lack any code level access.

This is probably a hail mary, but I figured I would ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so since you already have a url field:

- Set up a new rule where the event is `Content is viewed of type YourContentType`.
- Add a `Page redirect` action.
- For the destination use your field as a replacement pattern. So something like: `node:field-url`.

Just take note that you won't be able to view your content with this rule. But you can still access the edit page using the content management interface.

---

Just for your information, if you DO get access to the code:

You can use [`hook_node_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x) to create redirects. Since you already have the event URL in the node data you can use a [`drupal_goto`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x).

Here's a snippet I found in a [related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/redirect-to-an-external-site-when-accessing-the-page-of-a-node-meeting-a-set-of). I changed some things though.:

```
module_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full' && "Conditions") {
    // Change $node->url to what works.
    // Use the devel module and krumo() to check the contents of $node.
    drupal_goto($node->url);
  }
}
```

I've assumed you're using Drupal 7.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As I mentioned in the end of my first post though, I lack any access to coding. I was hoping the rules module, or something of that nature might help.

Comment: Missed reading that part, sorry. Let me get back to you.

Comment: Ok Comprox, updated!

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I feel silly for missing the page redirect in rules now.